# Rewrite URL on .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have urls like `www.example.com/de/something` and I need to redirect to `www.example.com` everything that starts with `/de/`.

At the moment I have done this

```
redirect 301 /de http://example.com
```

and it redirect all links but just removing `/de` part and result is `www.example.com/something`.

How to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds as if you have another rewrite rule that redirects to the "www host name" again.

Comment: I assume you are right. @starkeen answer worked for me but for a specific url (/de/something) it would redirect to (/something). Very annoying. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redirect directive matchs rest of the uri and appends it to the target, you can use RedirectMatch to redirect a specific uri

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/de/? http://example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want /de/ in the target you should have specified so, becasue Redirect will include in the target everything "after" what you have matched.

For a different virtualhost as the destination you want this:

```
Redirect 301 /de/ http://example.com/de/
```

or

```
Redirect 301 /de http://example.com/de
```

If what you want is redirect inside the same virtualhost /de to /, then use a negative lookahead.

```
RedirectMatch ^(?!de) http://example.com/
```

If the context is .htaccess, for virtualhost It would be:

```
RedirectMatch ^/(?!de) http://example.com/
```

Note: I use /de/ originally because that's what you describe in your question, and also I match slashes in the target. Both source and target without slashes would be fine too for cases like /desomething or /de/something. In any case, always match slashes or the lack of them.

Note2: Do not use .htaccess to redirect unless you are not the admin of the site. It just complicates things and adds unnecessary overhead since the file/s need to be checked a number of times per hit.

Comment: This will cause a redirect loop as your redirect's destination and pattern are identical.

Comment: Now that you say it I'm propably misunderstanding what he really wants. I took there werre different virtualhosts because in one case he says www.example.com and in the example he says example.com. Let me add another case just for that.